# She sells drugs "and" murdered a guy. - can you use a coordinating conjunction to joint verb phrases regardless of their tense structures?

Tags: tense, conjunctions

**Example 1**

> She sells drugs **and** murdered a guy.

**Example 2**

> She murdered a guy **and** sells drugs.

**Example 3**

> She murdered a guy **or** sells drugs.

I wonder if you can use a coordinating conjunction to joint verb phrases regardless of their tense structures.

I feel like Example 1 and 2 are both fine. They basically tell the reader that she sells drugs and that is what she does and tell the murder she committed in the past in two different orders.

However, I am not sure whether Example 3 is correct.

Comment: *She **killed** him, **is** under arrest, and **will go** to prison for it*. Nothing unusual about those tenses.

Comment: "She's a drug dealer and a murderer" would be more natural.

Comment: She sells drugs, murdered a guy, has been arrested, and will go to jail. Four tenses.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. If the conjuncts describe actions occurring at different times, then they can (and often should) use different tenses. Here are examples using "and", "or", and "but":

> So they couldn’t be entirely sure that their WhatsApp community, which **is called** ‘Antarctic Worms’ **and has reached** more than 240 members, could be sustained. (Christine Ro, "[How scientists are using WhatsApp for research and communication](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-023-01575-z)," Nature, 9 May 2023)

> It affects everyone who **has, or will have**, an elder family member or loved one in their lives—and everyone lucky enough to grow old themselves. (William A. Haseltine, "[Top 10 Tips For Caring For Older Adults](https://www.forbes.com/sites/williamhaseltine/2020/01/10/top-10-tips-for-caring-for-older-adults/)," *Forbes*, 10 January 2020)

> Corner Picks: Napoli's Scudetto win **is** a special accomplishment, **but will lead** to loss vs. Fiorentina (Tom Fornelli, "[Corner Picks: Napoli's Scudetto win is a special accomplishment, but will lead to loss vs. Fiorentina](https://www.cbssports.com/soccer/news/corner-picks-napolis-scudetto-win-is-a-special-accomplishment-but-will-lead-to-loss-vs-fiorentina/)," CBS Sports, 5 May 2023)

Your third example is grammatically correct but sounds unusual. (I wouldn't normally expect those two options.) If I had to write such a sentence, I'd probably insert "either" to make the meaning clearer:

> She either murdered a guy or sells drugs.

Comment: I agree that the OP's structures are valid, but your three examples don't illustrate the point perfectly, being just varied tenses of the same verb in the same use.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty That's true; it was easier to search for such examples. I've replaced the last example to one that has different main verbs and will try to update the others, too.